# how to remove "no hypervisor" option on windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, hypervisor

whenever i turn my pc on it shows 2 option i.e windows8.1 and Windows 8.1 with "no hypervisor" .I want to remove that option of windows8.1 with "no hypervisor" feature and want my pc to be normal again.What should i do?

Comment: Is Hyper-V enabled?

Comment: Yes , I recently checked my system it's enabled